# GTM Data Layer Variable Version 1 is not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I have created 3 data layer variables in my GTM container.

1. firstName - version 2
2. lastName - version 2
3. phoneNumber - version 1

**Expected output of Data layer after** `dataLayer.push`

1. In first event some one shares phone number
   `{firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Cena', phoneNumber: '999-999-999-9'}`
2. In second event he removes his phone number

   `{firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Cena'}`

**Current output of data layer after** `dataLayer.push`

1. In first event some one shares phone number
   `{firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Cena', phoneNumber: '999-999-999-9'}`
2. In second event he removes his phone number

   `{firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Cena', phoneNumber: '999-999-999-9'}`

Version 1 still works like Version 2

**Is it even possible to use combination of Version 1 and 2 or all variables should have same version?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use the combo of v1 and v2 as you see fit. And using v1 may be a solution to same object being pushed with different values. Depends on your pushed objects structure. V1 has its limitations however.

There's a very good article covering the difference and use cases for v1 and v2 [here](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/data-layer-variable-versions-explained/) from Simo. Basically, v1 only supports flat structure of the pushed data and no recursive merging of complex objects. Probably as a logical result of not recognizing the complexity of objects.

In your example, however, you have simple flat objects pushed to the DL, so you may not even notice the difference.

Comment: I actually came to know about the version through Simo's article but it does not covers the combo of v1 and v2. And when i tried this combo it had no impact i was still able to see the unused event property ( which has version V1 ) in data layer.

Comment: yep, it's cuz you're using flat objects. You would see the difference in nested objects, say if you would to push something like `{id:123,person:{firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Cena'}}`. Now accessing the person.firstName would only be possible with v2, v1 can't go inside objects, so now you'd make a CJS that would be able to return your `{{DLV v1}}.person` and related fields of that person object. Anyhow, v1/v2 does not solve your issue with un-nulled values in subsequent pushes.